# Hibernate INNER JOIN GROUP BY for Multiple class

Tags: hibernate, criteria, detachedcriteria

I am new to Hibernate, I want to convert the following query to Hibernate coding.

```
SELECT a.RegisterCount, b.Id, b.Type, COUNT(a.RegisterCount) AS Expr1 
FROM Student AS a INNER JOIN 
Search_OldStudent AS b ON a.StudentId = b.Id 
GROUP BY a.RegisterCount, b.Id, b.Type
```

In that, there is no primary relation between a.StudentId and b.Id. And also there is no mapping between them.

Can you please suggest how to do this one?

Comment: You can use session.createSQLQuery() to run this as a native SQL query if there are no additional constraints. By the way, if you are counting RegisterCount, the SQL query needs to be corrected. RegisterCount should not be added as a column in Select and  Group By clause

Comment: It will add more constraints based on criteria.